# Are there any way to read a xls file line by line in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a new VBA program and I need help.

Normally, the files I retrieve from the users contains csv extension so reading the file is quite easy.

Having the csv file I can read it and save every line in an array just like the following example:

```
Open strPath For Input As #1 ' Open file for input
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file
        linenumber = linenumber + 1
        Line Input #1, line
        arrayOfElements = Split(line, ";")
        lineCounter = lineCounter + 1
    Loop
Close #1 ' Close fil
```

Now, I must do the same with a xls file. This file will have n lines so, I need to read every line in a loop and save it into an array.

Is this possible?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You cann assign the UsedRange to an array directly. How many worksheets do you have in the xls file or are we talking about the first sheet always?

Comment: Have you tried doing it with exactly the same code? An xls file is plain text, same as a csv...

Comment: Hi. Only one. So I must search for UsedRange function, Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are really talking about an XLS File code could look like that

```
Sub ReadXLFileIntoArray()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("Filename")
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)

    Dim vDat As Variant
    ' Vdat will be an 2-dimensional array containing the data
    vDat = wks.UsedRange


End Sub
```

Comment: This looks fine. 

What if I need to open the file from Filepicker?

Comment: No problem, it does not matter how you open the file beforehand.